# remove duplicated words in string in c program

Tags: c, string, duplicates

I want to write a function that gets sentence (I call it resentence) and find duplicated words, and remove them.
ex:
input

```
Big happy happy smile
```

output

```
Big happy smile
```

It shows that there an error in the line :

```
if (strstr(temp1, temp) == NULL)
```

hope someone can find what is the deal.

```
void RemoveDuplicates(char *resentence)
{
char *temp1 = malloc(100);
char *temp = NULL;
int len;
len = strlen(resentence);
printf("len:%d", len);
temp = strtok(resentence, " ");


if (temp != NULL && strstr(temp1, temp) == NULL)
    strcpy(temp1, temp);

while (temp != NULL)
{
    temp = strtok(NULL, " ");

    if (strstr(temp1, temp) == NULL)
    {
        strcat(temp1, " ");
        strcat(temp1, temp);
    }
}
strcpy(resentence,temp1);
puts(resentence);
free(temp1);
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x5DEA49CE (msvcr120d.dll) in q1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.   I guess there is a memory error

Comment: first time `temp1` point to uninitialize area. `char *temp1 = malloc(100);` -->  `char *temp1 = calloc(100, 1);` or `char *temp1 = malloc(100);*temp1=0;`

Comment: "Access violation reading location 0x00000000" suggests dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Comment: I changed the char *temp1=malloc(100); *temp1=0; still the same error.

Comment: `if (strstr(temp1, temp) == NULL)` when `temp = strtok(NULL, " ");` `strtok` return `NULL`.

Comment: 1. You never initially terminate your target string, so concatenation invokes undefined behavior. 2. You never check the result of the `strtok` *in* the loop before using it (this is your NULL-deference). 3. Not a bug, but ideally, you shouldn't need to allocate any buffer memory to perform this *at all*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
void RemoveDuplicates(char *resentence){
    char *temp1 = malloc(100);
    char *temp = NULL;

    *temp1=0;
    temp = strtok(resentence, " ");

    if (temp != NULL){// && strstr(temp1, temp) == NULL)
        strcpy(temp1, temp);
        while ((temp = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL){
            if (strstr(temp1, temp) == NULL){
                strcat(temp1, " ");
                strcat(temp1, temp);
            }
        }
    }
    strcpy(resentence, temp1);
    puts(resentence);
    free(temp1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you input something like this: "abc ab" in this code, even in the corrected version it still is going to give a wrong output, in this case: "abc"(missing "ab"). This happens because of how the function "strstr()" works. It takes two strings, lets assume char *a = "abc" and char *b = "ab", and compares them to each other character by character. With strings a and b it would go as: 1) a = a (ok), 2) b = b (ok) and here it stops once "strstr()" doesn't compare the null terminator character '\0' letting us with a false confirmation of equality. Following is a small program I wrote for this same purpose and seems to work with any given input(at least with the ones I tried :] ), hope It helps.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 500 

void duplicateRemover(char *, const int);

int main(void)
{
    char someString[SIZE];

    puts("Enter text: ");
    fgets(someString, SIZE, stdin);

    someString[strcspn(someString, "\n")] = 0;

    printf("\n\n%s\n\n", "Text without repeated words: "); 
    duplicateRemover(someString, SIZE);
}

void duplicateRemover(char *arrayPtr, const int sizeP)
{
    char wordTable[sizeP][sizeP], *tokPtr;
    size_t i, j, k, l;

    tokPtr = strtok(arrayPtr, " ");

    strcpy(wordTable[0], tokPtr);

    for(i = 1; (tokPtr = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL; i++)
        strcpy(wordTable[i], tokPtr);

    for(j = 0; j <= i; j++) 
        for(k = j + 1; k <= i; k++) 
            if(strcmp(wordTable[j], wordTable[k]) == 0) {
                for(l = k; l < i; l++)
                    strcpy(wordTable[l], wordTable[l + 1]);
            k = j; 
            i--;
            }

    for(l = 0; l <= i; l++)
        printf("%s ", wordTable[l]);
}
```